# Machine learning or NLP approach to convert string about month ,year into dates

Tags: machine-learning, python, nlp, nltk, regex

I'm currently in the process of developing a program with the capability of converting human style of representing year into actual dates.
Example : **last year last month** into **December 2018**
string may be complete sentence like : **what were you doing 5 years ago**

it will gives **2014**

The purpose is to evalute human style of represting year or date into actual date, i have created collection of this type of strings and matching them with regex.

I have read some machine learning but I'm not sure which algorithm suits this problem the best or if I should consider using NLP.

Does anyone have a suggestion of what algorithm to use or where I can find the necessary literature to solve my problem?

Thanks for any contribution!

Comment: See : https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/45854/date-extraction-in-python/45855#45855

Comment: If any one need library to accomplish this then you can use datefinder,
It will detect all types of natural styles of dates.

Github Link: https://github.com/akoumjian/datefinder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got my answer , NLTK is good to go for this problem. 
You may use sutime with python wrapper :

[Python wrapper for Stanford CoreNLP's SUTime](https://github.com/FraBle/python-sutime)

The usual approach in NLP is to collect a dataset required for training. Process that dataset so that the words in the dataset are converted into numbers.

One simple example of converting it into numbers is to make a large dictionary of words from the dataset and use the index of each word in the dictionary as the representing number

Answer (score 0):

What you need to look for is called "Named Entity recognition". From [Wikipedia](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml)

> Named-entity recognition (NER) (also known as entity identification,
>   entity chunking and entity extraction) is a subtask of information
>   extraction that seeks to locate and classify named entity mentions in
>   unstructured text into pre-defined categories such as the person
>   names, organizations, locations, medical codes, time expressions,
>   quantities, monetary values, percentages, etc.

As it is mentioned in the comments section, Stanford has a great NER Tagger and you could use that together with Python (even if the StanfordNLP is implemented in Java)

Download the jar file from the [official url](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml). It has this format `stanford-ner-xxxx-xx-xx.zip`

You need to put the following two files in the same application folder as your Python script

1. ner-tagger.jar
2. ner-model-english.ser.gz (choose another one if you don't want English)

---

```
import nltk

from nltk.tag.stanford import StanfordNERTagger  

yourText = this_is_your_text

words = nltk.word_tokenize(yourText)
jar = './stanford-ner.jar'
model = './ner-model-english.ser.gz'

tagger = StanfordNERTagger(model, jar, encoding='utf8')

print(ner_tagger.tag(words))
```

Then you can grab from the above, anything that is tagged as `DATE`

Comment: ner-model-english.ser.gz is not present in that zip and i am trying to use other file from **classifier (english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz)**  but i always stuck with following error: `TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class StanfordTagger with abstract methods _cmd`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a temporal tagger. [This](https://github.com/HeidelTime/heideltime) is a good rule-based one.

Stanford CoreNLP also has [one](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/sutime.html).

It seems like generally rule-based approaches work well for this task.